# Date input placeholder has strange text color in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

My web page is rendering a native date input in a form. The input is initialised with no value so it's up to the browser to show a placeholder.

I've styled the text colour of the date input to be `rgb(0 50 50)`.

E.g. In in Firefox the placeholder (for my locale) is `dd/mm/yyyy`. It renders like this:

[image: date input placeholder rendering in Firefox]

In Safari (Version 15.6.1) however, perhaps due to some (arguably misguided) attempt to fade the placeholder text, the input's placeholder is rendered with a bright cyan text color. Presumably some adjustment of `rgb(0 50 50)`.

(It appears Safari uses the current date as the placeholder rather than `dd/mm/yyyy`, but this isn't relevant to the question.)

[image: date input placeholder rendering in Safari]

See example here:

```css
input {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: rgb(0 50 50);
}
```

```html
<input type="date" />
```

My question is first; is this a bug in Safari? This behaviour looks to be almost always undesirable except when the input text colour has very low saturation. Safari seems to be picking a colour for the placeholder based on some naïve adjustment of the base text colour.

Secondly, is there some way to target this placeholder text and override the colour somehow? I tried `::-webkit-datetime-edit` but this only affects the slashes between the date parts, not the actual text itself.

Comment: came here with the same issue ...

Comment: I have a quite similar issue

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer the second half of your question, but maybe it helps.

This is how I styled the text color in my version of Safari (17.1.2) and it works:

```
input[type="date"]::-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field,
input[type="date"]::-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field,
input[type="date"]::-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field,
input[type="date"]::-webkit-datetime-edit-text {
  color: red; // my custom color
}
```

My problem was that Safari renders all **disabled** `input[type="date"]` fields in the color `graytext` for some reason. This only occurs in Safari (**NOT** in Chrome or Firefox) and it seems using the hack above is the only way to override this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution.

The main moving parts are using `-webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0,0,255,.25);` with an rgba colour and javascript to add a class if the field has no value.

```js
// Select all input elements of type 'date'
const dateInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="date"]');
// Create a helper function
const toggleClass = (input) => input.classList.toggle('no-value', !input.value);
// Loop over the inputs
dateInputs.forEach(input => {
  // Add a js class as our colour hook
  input.classList.add('js');
  // Add an onchange listener
  input.addEventListener('change', (event) => toggleClass(event.target));
  // Toggle
  toggleClass(input);
});
```

```css
input[type=date] {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: rgba(0,0,255,1);
}
input[type=date].js.no-value {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0,0,255,.25);
  font-size: 20px;
  
}
```

```html
<input type="date">
<input type="date" value="2024-01-01">
```

It builds on information found here: https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-forms/issues/38#issuecomment-1897810020